# how to get uqnique identifier of table and column in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server

I can use this sql to get object_id, table name and column name.

```
select a.object_id,a.name,b.name as fieldName 
from sys.tables a
join sys.columns b on a.object_id=b.object_id 
order by 1,2,3
```

It seems that the object_id is the unique identifier of table. But when I change the structure of table, then object_id will be changed. And I don't know which is the unique identifier of column?
Are there unique identifier which never changed for table and column? Thanks a lot!

@SMor Thanks for your reminding. I want to monitor the change history of
database structure information,including table name, field name and data type of field etc. And then we can analyze the change history for project summary or other usages.

Comment: Short answer is no. But this smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since it is rare that the column_id of a column would be useful information.

Comment: The object_id will not change unless you drop and recreate the table. When you recreate a table, it's of course a new table and has no relation to the original. I agree with @SMor this is an XY problem. You might look into extended properties to attach meta-data of your choosing to objects and columns.

Comment: Slight detour but worth reading. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3 and also https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Comment: @SMor, I replenish some description of our requirement.

Comment: @Dan Guzman, Besides drop table , it seems that many operation will recreate the table info, for example change the fk, auto increased id. I'm not test it strictly; extened properties maybe available for me I will try it.

Comment: @Sean Lange Thans for your info.

Comment: _Besides drop table , it seems that many operation will recreate the table info, for example change the fk, auto increased id._ Not using raw SQL, it doesn't. Sounds like there's something else happening here such as some kind of ORM framework that drops and recreates tables when it migrates the database schema to a new version.

Comment: @Farwell_Liu, it is the tool you are using that's dropping the table. Tools may recreate the table to implement and facilitate changes but that's required only for some changes (e.g. column reordering).

Comment: Put your schema into an appropriate source-control tool and you solve this and many other problems.

Comment: Thank you all! I haven't found any good approach to this problem. It seems that the database doesn't support this directly.